# 'tf.keras.preprocessing.text_dataset_from_directory' function is not reading arabic text files

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I made a machine learning model that does sentiment analysis on english sentences, but now I want to train the same model for arabic sentences, however performance was bad unlike for english model, knowing that I used the same dataset translated in arabic. I noticed that the function from tensorflow `raw_val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.text_dataset_from_directory(train_dir, batch_size=batch_size, validation_split=0.2, subset='validation', seed=seed)` is not giving an output in arabic:

```
for text_batch, label_batch in raw_train_ds.take(1):
  for i in range(3):
    print("Review", text_batch.numpy()[i])
    print("Label", label_batch.numpy()[i])
```

Output:

```
Review b'.\xef\xba\xaa\xef\xbb\xb4\xef\xba\x9f \xef\xbb\xaa\xef\xbb\xa8\xef\xbb\x9c\xef\xbb\x9f \xef\xba\x80\xef\xbb\xb2\xef\xba\xb8\xef\xbb\x9f\xef\xba\x8d \xef\xba\xbe\xef\xbb\x8c\xef\xba\x91 \xef\xbb\x92\xef\xba\xa3\xef\xba\x8d\xef\xba\xaf \xef\xbb\xaa\xef\xbb\xa7\xef\xba\x87 .Quatermain \xef\xba\x94\xef\xba\xbc\xef\xbb\x98\xef\xbb\x9f 
Label 1
```

however in english:

```
Review b"David Mamet is a very interesting and a very un-equal director. His first movie 'House of Games' was the one I liked best, and it set a series of films with characters whose perspective of life changes as they get into complicated situations, and so does the perspective of the viewer.
Label 1
```

So I think that this the problem so if anyone can help I would appreciate that!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In this line you're converting your output to UTF-8 encoding.

```
print("Review", text_batch.numpy()[i], encoding='utf-8')
```

The reason why the characters in arabic text are printed in byte sequences and the characters in english text not, is that code point for arabic charachters is >=128 and for english characters <128. [(Reference)](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#:%7E:text=UTF%20stands%20for%20%E2%80%9CUnicode%20Transformation,by%20the%20corresponding%20byte%20value.)

Omitting the encoding argument, you should get the right output.

```
print("Review", text_batch.numpy()[i])
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I will edit my question, I have this output when using ```print("Review", text_batch.numpy()[i])``` and not ```print("Review", text_batch.numpy()[i], encoding='utf-8')``` knowing that it gives an error bcz ```print``` does not have such second argument.

Comment: In this case you could try to decode it. `print("Review", text_batch.numpy()[i].decode(encoding='utf-8'))` or in case the text is with cp720 encoded, you can try `print("Review", text_batch.numpy()[i].decode(encoding='cp720'))`